# How can I use interface of PHP that is installed on the linux operating system in window operation system?

Tags: php, linux, interface

I want to use the Windows operating system to develop my PHP code, but PHP is installed on the Linux operating system. My PHP code runs on the Linux operating system, so I want to use a Linux provided interface of PHP.  How do I do this?

Comment: you need a webserver on the linux system and to access this webserver on your windows machine with your web browser. That is what a lot of people out there are doing with php, by the way.

Comment: I do not want  to  use FTP .It`s seem to use file_get_contents("localhostIP/user_add.php?user_id=105’")),that is right?

Comment: FTP is another subject, it is a file transfer protocol. You absolutely don't have to.

Comment: If you want to use your linux as the web server then you do have to use a FTP client. Your linux must have `LAMP` installed that's why it's working for your windows you can use `WAMP` or `XAMPP` both are windows based very easy to use web servers, For you I think `WAMP` would be the better choice.

Comment: I use LAMP ,but I want to edit my PHP code in window operating sysytem,how can I do

Comment: I have installed vmware ,and have installed LAMP on it ,I also installed redis on it .I want to use redis in my PHP code ,but I edit my PHP code in window operating system ,how can I connect redis server in my PHP code,It is seem to use "file_get_contents("localhost/user_add.php?user_id=101")"?,is it right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want write your code on Windows, but run it on Linux. In this case you can use [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) or [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). I am not experienced with docker, but I can provide some information about Vagrant:

From [Vagrant docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/index.html):

> Vagrant is a tool for building and managing virtual machine environments in a single workflow. With an easy-to-use workflow and focus on automation, Vagrant lowers development environment setup time, increases production parity, and makes the "works on my machine" excuse a relic of the past.

It allows you to simulate real server inside your Windows environment, by running virtual machine. You can setup shared folders, so you can do your code writing inside your Windows, and run it inside virtual machine, which could be Linux environment with installed LAMP stack.

To learn more about it, there is plenty of articles on the internet, for example:
https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-vagrant-windows/

You can also use [puphpet](https://puphpet.com/) to easily setup configuration for your virtual machine.

By default, shared folders in vagrant are very slow, especially in Windows, to make it faster you can use NFS file system. There is a plugin for Windows called [winnfsd](https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd).